# Jekyll page.title returning curly braces

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm moving my blog over to Jekyll. The header of my articles are:

```
---
layout: post
title: My New Post
category: Web Development
---
```

I'm trying to use `page.title` but it's only returning `{}` on my posts layout. If you want the full code, [here's the repo.](https://github.com/justinchmura/justinchmura.github.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have liquid markup in your _layouts/post.html's yaml.  You already have title defined in your posts.

Please try taking it out and refreshing.

Comment: Wow, something so simple and I wasted tons of time on it. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: No problem.  Another pair of eyes can spot something you've been looking at and not seeing for ages.